# Why I am getting the exception ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, virtualenv, modulenotfounderror

I am learning Python and I am having a hard time to understand what's going wrong here. I am using Python3 on Mac 10.14, I am using Visual Studio Code as IDE

My code so far is just this:

```
`#!/usr/bin/venv python3 
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import SQLAlchemy

engine = SQLAlchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:password@local/hostsakila')`
```

The message I get is:

> Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
> No module named 'SQLAlchemy'
> File "/Users/hmnesman/Downloads/Documents_Local/Python_learning/Sql_Alchemy/sqlalchemy_test.py", line 4, in 
> import SQLAlchemy

I did some research and it looks like you get this error when your pip directory is set up in a different folder than your Python interpreter (at least that was what I understood).

But I am using a virtual environment, so it shouldn't be the case. I did the checks below in my terminal, and it looks ok to me.

> (venv) bash-3.2$ which pip
> /Users/hmnesman/Downloads/Documents_Local/Python_learning/Sql_Alchemy/venv/bin/pip

> (venv) bash-3.2$ which python3
> /Users/hmnesman/Downloads/Documents_Local/Python_learning/Sql_Alchemy/venv/bin/python3

I also did   `pip list` and confirmed that SQLAlchemy has been installed.

I hope my explanation is clear, please let me know if there is any other detail I am missing out to include.

Thanks

Comment: That's because your first line is using `/usr/bin/venv/python3` which is different than your installation of `/Users/...../Sql_Alchemy/venv/...`. Just either remove it, or make it point to your python3 installation.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/venv python3` doesn't look like a sensible shebang line no matter what.

Comment: I removed the shebang, still breaking, then I took a look at the folder with the library folder and tried with `import sqlalchemy` and it worked. Thanks!